# Line markers density

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, marker

I plot a couple of lines in log scale with a huge amount of points. I plot them in black using different line styles/markers. I use "markevery" property to decrease amount of markers. X-values change at even intervals.

The issue I have is that markers distributed unevenly - less of them near 0, and more near the right end of each line.
Is there are any way to get around this issue without nitpicking x-values, so that they will be "evenly" distributed on log-scale?

Comment: Can you provide sample code and sample image?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation for posting images, and imsc already provided minimal working code example and a solution in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the index of points you want to plot. In `logscale` these points should be non-uniformly distributed. You can try `logspace` to achieve it.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1,1e5)

# Normal plot
#plt.plot(x,x,'o-')

# Log plot
idx=np.logspace(0,np.log10(len(x)),10).astype('int')-1
plt.plot(x[idx],x[idx],'o-')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

generates:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to achieve. I have a hard time tweaking indexes in a way I want them to be. It feels like I found whole new dimension in this solution.